# Error in python (jupyter): index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Tags: python

I am an amature in python, I wrote a simple code in jupyter. But it is giving an error. I want to plot a function:

```
import numpy as np
import math as m
#from scipy import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y1=np.zeros(10)      
y2=np.zeros(360)   
x=np.array(range(10))
print("a")

    x=np.linspace(0,100,1)
    d=1.0
    y=np.linspace(0,100,1)
    sigma=np.linspace(0,100,1)
    for i in range(0,100,1):
        y[i]= x[i]**2+d**2`
```

However I am getting an output with error:
1.0

---

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
4 sigma=np.linspace(0,100,1)
5 for i in range(0,100,1):
----> 6     y[i]= x[i]**2+d**2
7     print(y[i])
8 #    sigma[i]=1/(y[i])

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

1.0

---

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
4 sigma=np.linspace(0,100,1)
5 for i in range(0,100,1):
----> 6     y[i]= x[i]**2+d**2
7     print(y[i])
8 #    sigma[i]=1/(y[i])

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
1.0

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
4 sigma=np.linspace(0,100,1)
5 for i in range(0,100,1):
----> 6     y[i]= x[i]**2+d**2
7     print(y[i])
8 #    sigma[i]=1/(y[i])

Help me find the problem please

Answer (score 2):

The error message is quite explanatory. Notice that

```
x=np.linspace(0,100,1)
```

is `[0.]`

Probably you wanted to write: `x=np.linspace(0,1,100)`. In the documentation https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html you can observe that the first two parameters are `start` and `stop`, while you probably wrote the number of samples `num` in place of `stop`

Same story for `y`